# In case of absolute values, isn't zero considered a positive value?

Tags: absolute-value

In the below image, it has been said that if x≤-4, then both |3x-3| and |2x+8| will be negative.

[image]

If x=-4, how can |2x+8| be negative? If x=-4, |2x+8| becomes zero which is a positive vale. So how can they say that **if x≤-4, then both |3x-3| and |2x+8| will be negative**? They can say it only when x is less than -4.

Similarly, in the following image, we can see it has been said that:

when x≤-5, then |x+5|=-(x+5)

[image]

But when x=-5, how can |x+5| be equal to -(x+5)? It should be zero, a positive value, shouldn't it?

Links of the site from which these two screenshots have been collected are below:

[1. Link of the first image](https://gmatclub.com/forum/for-how-many-integer-values-of-x-is-3x-3-2x-233947.html?fbclid=IwAR363GKBsajT4gSL4wFi0YxvBFtMKEwSksX-vcOgjZyvUErjoa4AHSJQf3k#p1804531)

[2. Link of the second image](https://gmatclub.com/forum/if-y-x-5-x-5-then-y-can-take-how-many-integer-vales-173626.html)

Comment: When $x=-5$ there is no difference between $-(x+5)$ and $x+5$. Also you should not say $|2x+8|$ is negative etc. Absolute values cannot be negative.

Comment: Is this part of a bigger question/explanation? Please share that too for some context

Comment: @sai-kartik, I have added the links of explanation. Please check.

Comment: $|3x - 3|$ and $|2x + 8|$ being negative is nonsense anyway; they're always at least $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, here is a graph to help [visually](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/elc7vz62sk). As you can see:[image]

Here we can notice that these absolute values can be factored as $$ y=3|x-1|,2|x+4|$$ because the coefficients are positive.

The definition of the absolute value is:
$$|f(x)|=-f(x),f(x)\le 0\ \mathrm{or} \ |f(x)|= +f(x), f(x)\ge 0,f(x)\in \Bbb R$$

Clearly, this means that the value is indeed negative, but in terms of simply having the negative sign in front to make the argument positive, like when $|-2|=-(-2)=2$.

In addition, the zero is neither negative nor positive hence the fact that $|0|=\pm 0=0$. This also means that the zero can be included in the negative or positive restriction of the function. Zero is not a positive nor negative value.

Finally, to restate your absolute value question, each absolute value function will be negated for x<-4, and 0 for x=-4 for y=2|x+4| where you can clearly see that the 4 and -4 will cancel after factoring, which does not necessarily mean that they will be negative, but rather in the 2nd quadrant where x<0, y>0. The roots are where each function is equal to 0.

So in conclusion, $sgn(0)=0, sgn(x<0)=-1,sgn(x>0)=1$ and a negative value in the absolute value will never output |x|<0 for $x\in\Bbb R$ because $$|x<0|=|-k,k\in \Bbb N|=-x=-(-k)=x=k$$